# Parse error code 207 iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm experiencing a really strange error with Parse. error code 207 is "MustCreateUserThroughSignup  207 Error code indicating that a user can only be created through signup."
In the code below, I do not create a user- I merely search for a user with an objectId. Note that self.currentPerson.objectId has the proper value at the time that the query is made

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
NSString *objID = self.currentPerson.objectId;
//[query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:objID];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:objID block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if(error){
        NSLog(@"hi");
    }

    if (!object) {
        NSLog(@"The getUser request failed.");
    }
    else {
        e.user = (PFUser*)object;
        e.firstNameLabel.text = ((PFUser*)object)[@"username"];
        e.distanceLabel.text = @"20 miles";
        e.numMutualFriendsLabel.text = @"50";
        e.lastActiveLabel.text = @"30 minutes ago";
        e.personalBioLabel.text = ((PFUser*)object)[@"bioDescription"];
    }
}];
```

Comment: PFUser naturally queries the _User class on parse.com, if you don't initialize this on applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions then you essentially can't query it because it hasn't been created to query. Parse allows you to create anonymous users. I would look into that. it's very resourceful, and Parse is known for the well documented guides.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you have a logged-in user?

Comment: Yes, I do have a logged in user @RyanKreager

Comment: @soulshined I understand that, however my [PFUser currentUser] is definitely created at this time. I'll check the anonymous user thing out, thanks

Comment: @PantyDropper3000 if you have a user logged in then you almost had it with the code you commented out. It will be where key objectID is equal to [PFUser currentUser] objectID]

Comment: for anyone reading this, a good link to look into is https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries/iOS and scroll down to "Setting the current User"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a workaround solution was to use this code. The Parse user classes are a bit funky and you have to use their stuff

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
PFUser *userAgain = (PFUser *)[query getObjectWithId:self.currentPerson.objectId];
e.user = userAgain;
```